# Need fast encryption

Tags: swift, encryption

I have a large data structure that I split up into 1024 byte fragments. I encrypt these fragments using AES256 (using CryptoSwift) and write this to a socket.

After finally getting this to work, I noticed performance is horrible. Its about a 1000x difference in performance between encrypting the data and no encryption. ChaChaPoly is touted as faster but when I tried it, I got about a 50% improvement which is still pretty bad (500x slower than no encryption).

Any suggestions on how I can speed this up? Alternative encryptions? AES parameter change? Anything?

This is running on an iPhone.

Comment: This depends heavily on how you're implementing your entire format (not just the AES block cipher). AES itself is very fast. Start by profiling the code and seeing where you're spending your time. Also note that  CryptoSwift has never promised to be fast. It just promises to be easy to use and amuse Marcin (it sometimes fails the latter). Still, if you're having a massive slow-down, it's more likely how you're using it rather than the framework. (It's hard to judge "1000x" here since we don't know the baseline.)

Comment: (code unseen, I'm laying my bets on either key generation (if it's *really* slow) or random number generation (if it's *pretty* slow).)

Comment: The key and iv are static. Its this one line of code that is causing the performance issue: let encrypted = try AES(key: [UInt8](key.utf8), blockMode: CBC(iv: iv), padding: .pkcs7).encrypt([UInt8](data))

Comment: I'd run the profiler deeper and see where the real bottleneck is (of course making sure to build it all in Release mode). And you can compare it to CommonCryptor, which is more annoying to use, but it's almost certainly faster than CryptoSwift. (See comments above... CommonCrypto uses the AES hardware acceleration on the phone that "normal" Swift can't easily access.)

Comment: (Encrypting a ton of 1024 byte blocks with CBC and a fixed IV and key is really insecure, BTW. It's not *quite* as bad as the ECB penguin (search for it), but it's definitely in the same ballpark.)

Comment: To your "1000x," that's suspiciously the same as what Marcin says it'll add for Debug builds, so do make sure you're running in Release. https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/discussions/975

Comment: I switched to CryptoKit and for the same data, the performance improved over two orders of magnitude.